# Streaming replication - obfuscating copy?

Tags: postgresql

I would like to use streaming replication in PG9 for QA - that is, stream data from production to QA. Caveat: I need to obfuscate data in QA (change password hashes, emails etc.).

Is it possible to achieve it with streaming replication? If not, are there any alternatives for an incremental update with on-the-fly obfuscation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're probably gonna have to roll something of your own here.  What I'd do is setup a trigger on the real table that puts an obfuscated / arbitrary value in the place of such things and shoves them into a table with the same name in an alternate schema.  then I'd replicate the db, with those tables substituted for the originals.  This way, no secure data leaves production, and you can use a pre-built replication engine (slony) without having to roll everything yourself.  If you need help on slony, go to the slony admin guide to get started.  It seems really complex, but it's not too bad, and once you get the hang of it you can do some really cool and amazing things with it.

Comment: a note of clarification:  I've been running PostgreSQL streaming replication for some time now.  It is a binary replication mechanism and because of this, you cannot isolate databases or tables within a database.  To isolate databases, you need to use PITR (Point In Time Replication) via log shipping.  With PITR you cannot pull off what you want either.  I like Scott's suggestion though!

Answer (score 1):

Clear and short answer: NO.

In PostgreSQL embedded streaming replication master and slave **have to be identical**. Not only you can't change particular records and fields, but also you can't change number of databases for example. Complete "database cluster" from the master (with all its databases, tables, and data) will be copied to the slave.

What you actually need is some kind of logical, trigger based replication. I've heard that pglink can do this, but I've never tried.